# Actionscript 3 - How can i convert from XMLList to XML?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

My function is returning XML, so i do:

return xml.blah.blah.blah

It tells me it can't convert XMLList to XML

so i'm guessing xml.blah.blah.blah is a XMLList.

How can i do this (convert XMLList to XML)? the simpliest way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just cast the XMLList to XML.
Either:

```
XML(xml.blah.blah)
```

or

```
(xml.blah.blah as XML)
```

Comment: you're right, i didn't noticed the XML before the xml.blah.blah.blah
sorry for that, i already marked your answer as right. thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

You can access items of an XMLList like you would an array:

```
var booksXML:XML =
<Books>
    <Book ISBN="0000000000">
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <author>Author 1</author>
    </Book>
    <Book ISBN="1111111111">
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <author>Author 2</author>
    </Book>
    <Book ISBN="2222222222">
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <author>Author 3</author>
    </Book>
    <Book ISBN="3333333333">
        <title>Title 4</title>
        <author>Author 4</author>
    </Book>
</Books>;


var authorList:XMLList = booksXML.Book.author;

for (var i:int = 0; i < authorList.length(); i++)
{
    var authorElement:XML = authorList[i];
    trace(authorElement);
}
```